# json inside function, (php parsing)

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have sth like that inside *.txt file.

```
function_name({"one": {"id": "id_for_one", "value": "value_for_one"}, ...});
```

And I am getting the file like this:

```
$source = 'FILE_NAME.txt';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($source),true);
echo $json['one']['value'];
```

It doesn't work, but when I remove `function_name(` and `);` it works.
How to parse it without removing these strings?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That should be a JS callback function.

Comment: The hells are you doing? json_decode() is meant for decoding a JSON string. The string you are giving it is not a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your text file, means that isn't a json file.

Remove the string using a regular expression, and your problem is fixed.

If the function is a fixed name, do something like this:

```
$source = 'FILE_NAME.txt';
$json_content = str_replace('function_name(', '', file_get_contents($source));
$json_content = substr($json_content,0,-2);
$json = json_decode($json_content,true);
echo $json['one']['value'];
```

Comment: What if the `function_name` appears in JSON as well?

Comment: if is inside the JSON, then will become an string. Or will invalidate your object and if is invalid, isn't a JSON too. Take a look in this article http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is not valid JSON with those. Take a substring that excludes them.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove those strings.  With the function_name portion it is not valid JSON.

A JSON string will typically either begin with `{` (object notation) or `[` (array notation), but can also be scalar values such as a string or number.  You cannot parse it without first making sure the string is valid JSON.

Comment: JSON does not have to be enclosed in an object or array.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the string within a file and decoding it as a JSON file.

The 'function_name' isn't a valid JSON string, the rest inside yes.

Answer (score 1):

> How to parse it without removing these strings?

There is no way.
This should work for you.

```
$data = file_get_contents($source);
$data = substr($data, strlen("function_name("));
$data{strlen($data)-1}=$data{strlen($data)-2}=" ";
$json = json_decode($data,true);
```

Both `{}` and `[]` works for string to access individual characters.